# R: How to subset data by two factor columns, then run Fisher's Exact Test for each subset?

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame that looks like so:

```
Spec.   Month      SampleMethod    Prey1     Prey2 
 AR     April         Opp          37.2      23.2
 AR     April         Clu          40.1      19.2
 AR     April         Hom          2.4       70.1
 MR     April         Opp          34.2      27.2
 MR     April         Clu          48.1      13.2
 MR     April         Hom          10.4      5.4
 AR     May           Opp          32.2      21.2
 AR     May           Clu          42.1      11.2
 AR     May           Hom          8.9       71.1
```

What I want to do is run a Fisher's exact test on every combination of the SampleMethod for each species in each month (e.g. "Clu" vs. "Opp"; "Opp" vs. "Hom"; "Hom" vs. "Clu"). I know how to do this by selecting out every single pair and making each pair a new data frame and then running Fisher's test. However, I would like to do it in this one data frame and in an efficient manner. How does one specify for example that I want to select the "Opp" Sample Method from the Month of "April" from species "AR" and compare that to the "Clu" SampleMethod from the Month of "April" from Spec. "AR". I essentially am trying to do that and then run a Fisher's exact test on those two selected rows. I then have to repeat that for the 7 different species over 6 different months so any help on how to do this would be great.

Comment: Please post the code that you have written.

Comment: @user2923027 What I would do is essentially split it up by each species for each month  so that each would be its own data frame. The code (using the dplyr package) would be AR<-filter(DF, Spec.=="AR", Month =="April") and then it would keep going for each Spec. for each month. However this seems extremely inefficient

Answer (score 0):

By using nested `sapply` functions, we'll perform Fisher's Exact Test on data subsets for each combination of `Spec.` and `Month` and for each pairwise combination of `SampleMethod` within each subset.

The code below returns all the results in a list with elements for each combination of `Spec.` and `Month`, and sub-elements for each pair of `SampleMethod`. It is these sub-elements that contain the output of the test.

```
FT.list = sapply(split(DF, list(DF$Spec., DF$Month)), function(dat) {

  # If there are at least two rows in a data subset, then proceed with Fisher Test
  if(nrow(dat)>=2) {

    # Get all pairwise combinations of SampleMethod
    SMs = combn(unique(dat$SampleMethod), 2, simplify=FALSE)

    # Name each element of SMs so that sapply will return the names in each list element
    names(SMs) = lapply(SMs, paste, collapse=", ")

    # For each pair of SampleMethod, run Fisher's Exact Test
    sapply(SMs, function(methods) {
      dat = dat[dat$SampleMethod %in% methods, ]
      fisher.test(dat[, grep("Prey", names(dat))])
    }, simplify=FALSE)

  }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. The one issue that makes this challenging is that I am trying to use frequency data to run a fisher.test not count data. Thus my dependent variables Prey1 and Prey2 are separate variables not the same. As such I need a way to specify that I am comparing the diet (which are both the Prey1 and Prey2 items) in one sample method in one month from one species to the diet from the same species in the same month but from a different sample method.

Comment: The code I can use to do this is simply manually entering in the values of each then running the Fisher test. The code looks like                                        "fisher.test (rbind (c(37.2, 23.1,9.1, etc.), c(40.1,19.2,3.2, etc.))". But that takes forever and is inefficient. How could I do something as simply as specify the "cells" that I want to compare? In excel it would be B4:B7 (all of the prey variables) compared against C4:C7. I do not know how to specify that in R though as I am a novice. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste into your question the exact code you would run for one of these Fisher tests on a subset of your data? Not the by-hand method in your comment, but extracting one relevant subset of your data then running the test on that subset. (Ideally, you would paste in a data sample of that subset using `dput` as well.) Then I think I can fill in my answer with the code for running the test on each subset.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you would like but here is an example of some code I have been using though also inefficient. fisher.test(rbind(DF[2,4:7],DF[3,4:7]))...I have to verify this is running the test correctly but I believe this is comparing the diets of the 2nd and 3rd rows (assuming the headers are the first row)

Comment: Just double checked this by comparing the results to manually entering in the data and it works. However, the problem is it requires me to do each one manually and keep track of which is being compared to which!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `rbind(DF[2,4:7],DF[3,4:7])`. The sample data you provided has only 5 columns, but you select columns 4 through 7 in your code.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. In the data I am using there are more Prey variables then in the sample data. If I was only using the sample data it would be `rbind(DF[2,4:5],DF[3,4:5])`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I recommend we delete the comment thread, since it's no longer relevant to the final code. If you agree, go ahead and delete your comments and then I'll delete mine.